# Get distinct results from several tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I need to implement mysql query to calculate space used by user's mailbox.
A message thread may have multiple messages (reply, follow up) by 2 parties
(sender/recipient) and is tagged with one or more tags (Inbox, Sent etc.).

The following conditions have to be met: 
a) user is either recipient OR author of the message;
b) message IS TAGGED by any of the tags: 1,2,3,4; 
c) distinct records only, ie if the thread, containing messages is tagged with
more than one of the 4 tags (for example 1 and 4: Inbox and Sent) the calculation 
is done on one tag only

I have tried the following query but I am not able to get distinct values - the 
subject/body values are duplicated:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(subject)+LENGTH(body)) AS sum 
FROM om_msg_message omm 
JOIN om_msg_index omi ON omm.mid = omi.mid
JOIN om_msg_tags_index omti ON omi.thread_id = omti.thread_id AND omti.uid = user_id
WHERE (omi.recipient = user_id OR omi.author = user_id) AND omti.tag_id IN (1,2,3,4) 
GROUP BY omi.mid;
```

Structure of the tables:

1. om_msg_message - fields subject and body are the ones to be calculated

   ```
   +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
   +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | mid          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   | subject      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | body         | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | timestamp    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
   | reply_to_mid | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
   +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   ```
2. om_msg_index

   ```
   +-----+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+
   | mid | thread_id | recipient | author | is_new | deleted |
   +-----+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+
   |   1 |         1 |      1392 |   1211 |      0 |       0 |
   |   2 |         1 |      1211 |   1392 |      1 |       0 |
   +-----+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+---------+
   ```
3. om_msg_tags_index

   ```
   +--------+------+-----------+
   | tag_id | uid  | thread_id |
   +--------+------+-----------+
   |      1 | 1211 |         1 |
   |      4 | 1211 |         1 |
   |      1 | 1392 |         1 |
   |      4 | 1392 |         1 |
   +--------+------+-----------+
   ```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(omm.subject) + LENGTH(omm.body)) as totalLength
FROM om_msg_message omm
JOIN om_msg_index omi 
  ON omi.mid = omm.mid
     AND (omi.recipient = user_id OR omi.author = user_id)
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT thread_id
      FROM om_msg_tags_index
      WHERE uid = user_id
            AND tag_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)) omti
  ON omti.thread_id = omi.thread_id
```

I'm assuming that:

1. `user_id` is a parameter marker/host variable, being queried for an individual user.
2. You want the total of all messages per user, not the total length of each message (which is what the `GROUP BY` clause in your version was getting you).
3. That `mid` in both `om_msg_message` and `om_msg_index` is unique.

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem is the IN clause.  I'm not a MYSQL guru, but in T-SQL you could change it to have a where clause on a subquery that contained an EXISTS so your join didn't pop out two rows.  You need to compensate for the fact that you have two rows with different tagID's associated with each row of your primary join data.

The way I could do it cross-platform would be with four left-joins that linked tables then demanded a non-null value for 1, 2, 3, or 4.  Fairly inefficient; I'm sure there's a better way to do it in MySQL, but now that you know what the problem is you might know a better solution.

Comment: Um, the `WHERE EXISTS` clause is part of the SQL Standard, and would likely be more efficient than the `LEFT JOIN`s.  However, your diagnosis of the problem is spot on.

Comment: @Dylan Thanks for your help! I went with Clockwork-Muse's solution as it actually does solve the problem for me.